# Two divs, one at 60% and the other taking the rest

Tags: html, css

I've two div, the first one take 60% and the other one is just on top of it.
I want the div "Shop" taking 60% horizontally and "Gameplay" would take the rest still horizontally.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#Shop {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Gameplay {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main" id="main">
  <div class="content" id="Shop">
    <h1>Laboratoire des tests JS </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="Gameplay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because "float: left;".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make the parent `display: flex;` and apply `width: 60%;` to `#Shop`.
Then you can either apply  `flex-grow: 1` or `width: 40%;` to `#Gameplay` to give it remaining width

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#Shop {
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#Gameplay {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: hotpink;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main" id="main">
  <div class="content" id="Shop">
    <h1>Laboratoire des tests JS </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="Gameplay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried, but doesnt change #Gameplay placement